# How to get GPS coordinates of neighborhood polygon from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, gps, coordinates

Does anyone know how I can find the GPS coordinates for neighborhoods like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/SoHo,+New+York,+NY/@40.7236448,-74.0006793,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c2598c5e51e2f3:0xce2f3449f490f818

[image]

Not just in New York, but ideally anywhere else in the US.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As it stands I am unclear what you mean by GPS coordinates, and therefore what you are asking.  If you mean latitude and longitude then it is 40.7236448 decimal degrees N,74.0006793 decimal degrees W.  If you are trying to convert decimal degrees (DD) to degrees minutes and seconds (DMS) then it should be possible to google a convertor, or do the maths (60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in a degree).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I mean the GPS coordinates for the polygon around a neighborhood.